# Spring OAuth2 Refresh token

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am having trouble getting to use the refresh token. Looking at the configuration of the endpoint: /oauth/token:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
```

it states that you have to be fully authenticated which makes sense. Alas, the second part which is refreshing your token uses the same endpoint (just state: grant_type=refresh_token).

BUT: you should not be authenticated to get a refresh token. So how is it possible to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some nice help from the spring team. I will "copy" their answer here.

The security protection on the /oauth/token is Oauth2 and not basic spring security. If you provide a client id and a client secret you can get through. So not basic!

Thanks spring!

Comment: I'm not sure which member of the Spring team that is "copied" from, but it doesn't look very accurate, so I'd guess that something got lost in the translation.  The token endpoint is secure, and the spec recommends using HTTP Basic authentication (with client credentials), so that's what Spring OAuth does by default.

Comment: Hello, I'm also facing this issue. Can you share how did you solve it?